# Выполнение кода с оперативной памяти

Tags: python, ram

Можно ли запустить код в Python, который будет сформирован в оперативной памяти? Есть зашифрованный мной python код и я не хочу чтобы любой мог увидеть реализацию, есть второй файл файл, который при вводе пароля должен расшифровать первый файл в оперативную память и запустить его. В итоге промежуточный расшифрованный файл не будет храниться на диске и при завершении работы второго файла просто "исчезнет". Можно ли такое реализовать? Другие языки не предлагать, библиотеки можно.

Comment: Да, реализовать такое можно. И в подобных вопросах неплохо бы указывать ОС, потому что в Юниксах такое куда проще реализуется.

Comment: ОС Windows 10. Я думал решение будет универсальным для все ОС

Comment: Расшифрованный файл можно будет без проблем вытащить из оперативной памяти

Comment: Кроме всего прочего, такое поведение может заинтересовать антивирус. Антивирусы очень не любят, когда в оперативной памяти что-то формируется и потом запускается. Обычно так вирусы делают.

Comment: Вы снова отвечаете на свой вопрос, а не на мой. Я понимаю, что Вы хорошо разбираетесь в этой области, но меня интересовало конкретное решение. Когда будет возмущаться антивирус, я задам следующий вопрос либо найду сам решение.

Comment: @RubiniuM С таким отношением к сообществу вам реально придётся в итоге все решения самому искать. Это нормально, когда ваш вопрос люди не сразу нормально понимают (для этого его нужно ещё идеально сформулировать) и когда дают ответы в меру своих знаний, не обязательно совпадающих с компетенцией, нужной для решения конкретного вопроса. Что бы вы предпочли - чтобы вам никто не отвечал вообще или чтобы люди пытались ответить хоть что-то в той мере как они поняли вопрос и какие знания у них есть?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - через `eval`:

```
eval(decrypt(secret, password).decode())
```

Есть ещё загрузчик кода, может кто напомнит как его там. Потом можно записать свой загрузчик модулей, который примет шифрованный код.

Но самое простое прогнать через cython и шифрование не нужно будет.

Comment: Eval очень ограничен, если не ошибаюсь. В нем нет возможности запустить циклы, про что-то сложнее я уже молчу

Comment: Ваш ответ натолкнул на правильное решение, спасибо. Это был exec

Comment: @RubiniuM неспалось, писал с телефона. Вот вертелось на языке - не вспомнил как его...

Answer (score 2):

К чему был вопрос насчёт ОС. На Юниксах (MacOSX, Linux) вместо `eval` и `exec` можно легко записать массив данных в оперативку по пути [/tmp/*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), а потом использовать [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) для загрузки и выполнения кода из множества взаимосвязанных нормальных Питонячих файлов, после чего их удалить. В принципе, на Винде можно сделать аналогично просто в какой-то скрытой локации на диске, от безопасности не сильно убудет: как высказывались другие участники, все упомянутые способы – такая себе защита от реальных злоумышленников и просто айтишников, но в целом варианты рабочие.

Comment: Такого ответа я как раз и ждал. Про безопасность не думайте. Я привёл лишь пример кода, который не связан с реальным проектом. Пусть будет хоть самодополняющийся код в оперативке, хоть scratch на python. Мое главное условие не сохранять файл на диск перед выполнением. Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Все решилось банально: Дешифруем файл в переменную и запускаем через exec. Всё.